# python regex extract match object

Tags: python, match, regex-group, python-re

This question has been asked before, but I'd like to re-ask it to provide another (perhaps more simple and to the point) example with a different spin.

Consider the following python regex and it's result.

```
import re

t = "The rain falls in Spain"
x = re.search("^The.*Spain$", t)

if x:
  print("There's a match!")
else:
  print("There's no match")

print (x)
```

Yields the following result:

```
There's a match!
<re.Match object; span=(0, 23), match='The rain falls in Spain'>
```

My question is simple.

How does one get the match object from the result?

Most of the other questions seem to address this topic in many different languages.  The few on python seem to use compile, which I didn't quite grasp anyway, so I am wondering if there are other ways to do it?  The simplest way is usually the best, I think.

Comment: So what are you trying to match here - i.e. which part do you need to retrieve? I assume it's the "rain falls in".

Comment: Try: `x.group()`, if you want only the variable part you need to surround the `.*` with parentheses: `(.*)`

Comment: It says, "<re.Match object; span=(0, 23), match='The rain falls in Spain'>. so match='The rain falls in Spain'. That last part.  I'm sorry, I dont seem to be able to put code into the comment window to make it any clearer.

Comment: right, but that's the entire string. I feel it would be somewhat pointless if you wanted to retrieve the input string itself in a match?

Comment: For example, your input string is `t`, you already have the desired value within the string variable itself.

Comment: okay, ty.  I see your point.  let me work on it a moment.  I seem to remember coming across other example where the match object is defined differently from the input string.  so that's why I was asking.

Comment: @ArnieHopkins I added an answer below - let me know if was what you were asking about.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you meant to find the phrase "The rain falls in Spain" within a larger string:

```py
import re

t = "Hello G'day. The rain falls in Spain. Testing 123."
x = re.search("The.*Spain", t)

if x:
  print("There's a match!")
  print(f'The match is: {x.group(0)!r}')
  print('The span is:', x.span(0))
else:
  print("There's no match")

print(x)
```

Output:

```
There's a match!
The match is: 'The rain falls in Spain'
The span is: (13, 36)
<re.Match object; span=(13, 36), match='The rain falls in Spain'>
```

**What did I change:**

- I removed `^$` from the regex, because we don't want to check for the start and end of a string explicitly. The desired match can also be somewhere within the string as well.
- Access a captured group number `n` using the syntax `x.group(n)`. In the above example, you can also use `x.group()` as a shortcut to get the first captured group (i.e. the first match)
- Access the start/end indices within the input string, of a captured group `n` (i.e. a match), using the syntax `x.span(n)`. Similarly as above, you can use `x.span()` as a shortcut to get the span of the first match.

Comment: That's very helpful, ty. :)  But one other way to sort of think of my question would be to ask...  what if you wanted to capture the span=(13, 36) part somehow?

Comment: hmm, I'm not too sure. what would be the span=(13,36) part again?

Comment: just look at the result...  it's right there in the entire third line of the result..  i cant copy an paste it into the comment box here

Comment: I hope I asked the question as I intended it.  It may be more of an OOP than a regex issue.  Somehow the object (in this case it is an re.Match object;) has the properties  span=(13, 36), match='The rain falls in Spain'...  so I am trying to figure out how to access those... that is, the values of...  span and match

Comment: Oh, I think I understand - you mean the substring indices in the input string.

Comment: @ArnieHopkins I updated to include usage of retrieving the span from a Match object

Comment: Very cool.  Thank you very much! :)

Comment: one follow up question...  I can see why x.span could access the indices, but why then didnt we use x.match to get the match='The rain falls in Spain' value? we has to use x.group to get the value of match='The rain falls in Spain'.  It would seem like we should have used x.match the way I am thinking through it right now.

Comment: @ArnieHopkins that's a good question, not entirely sure. I have tested and confirmed that Match objects dont have a `match` attribute, but I've always used `group()` anyway to get the match result. There's also [docs here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#match-objects) on the re.Match object that you can check out as well. I didn't see anything mentioned about a match attribute however.